# How can I change char array to int array in c++ and store it separately

Tags: c++, arrays

I don't know how to use the `atoi` function. If I change `atoi(e)` to `atoi(e[i])`, it produces an error.

How can I store the data separately, for example tmp[0]=3 tmp[1]=5

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char  e[11]="3596047218";
    int max=0,tmp[11];
    cin >> e;
    max = strlen(e);
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        tmp[i]= atoi(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: a. you need to read about nul terminated strings and after that b. consider using a safer function that `atoi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`atoi` doesn't accept `char`s as an argument, it accepts c-strings (`const char*`). When you subscript a char array, you return a reference to a char. This is what is causing the error. You don't actually need `atoi` at all to solve your problem, nor do you need `std::cin`. This is what your code should look like:

```
int main(){
    char e[11]="3596047218"; //initialise array

    int tmp[11]; //initialise array of ints
    max = 11;

    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++){
        //turn char into int, if char is a digit, and assign to corresponding 
        //    value in array
        if(e[i] <= '9' && e[i] >= '0') tmp[i] = int(e[i]-'0');
        //otherwise, assign a default value
        else tmp[i] = 0;
    }
}
```